# Tab active add remove class in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have two tabs for which I want to add the `active` and remove the `active` class. So I tried below code for the same.

```js
function EnableDisableTab() {
    alert('test');            
    $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
    $(".tab-pane").addClass("active");
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#bulk" aria-controls="bulk" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bulk Upload</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#single" aria-controls="single" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Single Update</a></li>
</ul>
   
   
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="bulk">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitUpload" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-default button" OnClick="btnSubmitUpload_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelUpload" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn btn-default button" OnClick="btnCancelUpload_Click" />
    </div>
</div>  



<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="single">
    <h1>This is test tab 2 </h1>
</div>
```

Please suggest what is wrong

Comment: Where do you call `EnableDisableTab`?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: I am calling it in server side click, also the alert is working fine

Comment: Do you want to switch between the tabs?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: yes but on `EnableDisableTab` function I want to make `single` div enabled

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen: any help mate ?

Comment: Have you tried `$(".tab-pane").toggleClass("active");`

Comment: yes but not totally. I mean to say, the div of the second('single update') gets enabled but the class remains active on the first div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200890/discussion-between-b-n-and-carsten-lovbo-andersen).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add and remove class on the same element. Instead try to get different id's not class as they are same.

```
$(".tab-pane")
```

This is return all the elements with class ".tab-pane". Use different id's instead.

Comment: yes with ID, the single tab div data is coming but the tab of Bulk Upload data is still showing active `$("#bulk").removeClass("active");
            $("#single").addClass("active");`

Comment: As suggested by Jakub you can try using ```$("#bulk").toggleClass("main"); $("#single").toggleClass("active");```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggleClass, as you are adding and removing the class at the same time 
https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/